# Losing mouseover event after drag/drop

Tags: javascript

I have a page that has scrollable div of strings and a separate grid made up of several divs.

Normally, a mouseover on the strings highlights them as I roll over.

After I drag a string from the upper set of divs into one of the grid divs, the mouseover highlighting no longer works until after I click the mouse again (doesn't matter where). Buttons in a separate div on the same page don't highlight either on mouseover.

I can click on any div (including the drop target) to get mouseover highlighting back, so it's just the act of clicking that seems to reenable the mouseover event.

This only happens after a drop. I tried generating a click and setting the ev.target to 0 ondragend (which I normally don't listen for), but still no dice (tried with focus, too, but I don't think that's the issue).

If the mouseover event isn't firing after the drop or isn't visible to other elements, how do I get it back without manually clicking the mouse?

[image: the problem area]

```
///////////////////////////////// D&D /////////////////////////////////////////
function hdragstart(e) {
   e.dataTransfer.setData("text", e.target.id);
   e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(e.target.innerHTML);
   return true;

}

function hdragenter(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return true;
}

function hdragover(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); 
}


function hdrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  e.target.innerHTML=(document.getElementById(data).innerHTML);
  e.target.title=(document.getElementById(data).innerHTML);
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}


//load saved streams into strcont div
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function loadsched()
{
    var fs=require('fs');
    var root,r,istr;
    var arr=[],len,buf,i,elt=[],elc=[],tn=[];

    buf  = fs.readFileSync(DS.DBFNAME,'utf8');
    arr  = buf.split('\n');
    len  = arr.length;
    root = document.getElementById('strcont');

    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        if((arr[i].search('des'))>-1){

            istr=i.toString();
            r   = dbgettag('des',arr[i]);

            elt[i] = document.createElement('div');
            elt[i].setAttribute('class','schedtxt');
            elt[i].setAttribute('id','sc'+istr);
            elt[i].setAttribute('draggable','true');

            tn[i]  = document.createTextNode(r);

            elt[i].appendChild(tn[i]);
            root.appendChild(elt[i]);   

            elc[i] = document.createElement('div');
            elc[i].setAttribute('class','clear');
            root.appendChild(elc[i]);   


        }
    }
}


///////////////////////////////// HTML /////////////////////////////////////////
  <div class='strcont' id='strcont'></div>  

  <div  class="grid" id="grid">
    <div class="cell0"  id="sel"  draggable="true" ondragstart="gdrag(event,this.value)"  onfocus="this.blur()" value="" title="Drag this to a time-slot" ></div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="12" >12</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="1"  >1</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="2"  >2</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="3"  >3</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="4"  >4</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="5"  >5</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="6"  >6</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="7"  >7</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="8"  >8</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="9"  >9</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="10" >10</div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="11" >11</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="AM" >AM</div>
    <div class="cell"  id="0"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)"></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="1"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)"></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="2"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="3"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="4"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="5"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="6"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="7"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="8"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="9"   ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="10"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="11"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="cell0"  disabled="disabled"   value="PM" >PM</div>
    <div class="cell"  id="12"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="13"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="14"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="15"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="16"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="17"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="18"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="19"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="20"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="21"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="22"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
    <div class="cell"  id="23"  ondrop="return hdrop(event)" ondragover="return hdragover(event)"  ondragenter="return hdragenter(event)" ></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

I did some further testing, just to try and better see what was happening.
I'm calling this function from:

```
<div class='strcont' id='strcont' onmouseover='return logMouseMove(event)'></div>  


function logMouseMove(e)
{
    var evt=e.type
    console.log(evt+" target="+(e.target||e.srcElement).id,'move')
    return false
}
```

It shows that the mouseover events fire on the strings after the drop, but highlighting is still not working until after I click the mouse, so I still don't know what's up with this, I'll see if I can drill down a little deeper:

```
wjs version: 0.12.3
test3.html:4097 streams-mf.txt
test3.html:2823 canplay
test3.html:2827 play

////// initial mouseover on strings
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=strcont move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc7 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc6 move

///// dragover on cell-4 div
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=4 move

///// drop on cell-3 div
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=3 move

///// dragend - mouseover back to strings div
test3.html:4124 mouseover target= move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=strbut move

///// mouseover events fired on strings divs
///// but no highlighte until clicked
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc7 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc6 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc5 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc4 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc3 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc2 move
test3.html:4124 mouseover target=sc1 move
```

Just a thought: the test I did showed mouseover fired without incident after a drop and without me clicking the mouse afterwords, so if I were to listen for the event in js, I could do the text-highlighting and it would work, so there's a workaround.

However, I change the text color in a css selector (the schedtxt class are dynamically created divs that scroll inside of the strcont div), why would I need to click the mouse after a drop to get the browser (Chromium/V8 in my case) to handle the css rule?

```
.strcont{
    width:      96%;
    height:     115px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    cursor:     default;
}

.schedtxt{
    width:      100%;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    font-family:arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:  11px;
    font-weight:600;
    color:      #aaaaaa;
    padding:0px 0px 0px 5px;
    overflow:   hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    cursor:     default;
}

.schedtxt:hover{
    color:#ececec;
}
```

EDIT:

Modifying the above testing function works as expected and fixes the problem, but there's still the question as to why I even need to do this when a css rule should handle it.

```
//workaround for mouseover highlight after drop problem
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function logMouseMove(e)
{
    var evt=e.type;
    var idt=(e.target||e.srcElement).id;

    if((idt.indexOf('sc')>-1)||(idt.indexOf('playon')>-1)||(idt.indexOf('scsav')>-1))
    {
        var el=document.getElementById(idt);
        if(evt=='mouseover') el.style.color='#ededed';
        if(evt=='mouseout')  el.style.color='#aaaaaa';
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: well, where is your code?

Comment: you want all 4356 lines? wouldn't do much good without the css, nwjs and the node-modules  too. I can't carve-out just the div I'm working on and still get it to run, how about just the D&D stuff - that's where it's losing it.

Comment: 4356 lines would be more informative than zero lines. How do you expect an answer with your question as is? A isolated example would be ideal, and yes, you can carve it out. Just about every question on here includes just that.